# Static initialization of int array from within structure initialization

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, structure, static-initialization

I'm trying to statically declare and initialize a structure array containing both char and int arrays.

The following example works well.

```
typedef struct myStruct
{
    char* name;
    uint8_t size;
    uint8_t *value;
}myStruct;

uint8_t struct1_value[] = {0x00, 0x01};
uint8_t struct2_value[] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x03, 0x04};

myStruct myStructArray[] = {
    [0] = {
        .name = "Struct_1",
        .size = 2,
        .value = struct1_value,
    },
    [1] = {
        .name = "Struct_2",
        .size = 4,
        .value = struct2_value,
    },
};
```

I can't find a syntax that allows to initialize `value` field directly from `myStructArray`

I would like to know if there is a way to initialize the `value` field without having to declare `struct1_value` and `struct2_value` variables.

Maybe it's just not possible in pure C but as it's possible to statically initialize a `char` array, why not with a `int` array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [compound literals](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compound-literals-c/).

```
myStruct myStructArray[] = {
    [0] = {
        .name = "Struct_1",
        .size = 2,
        .value = (uint8_t[]){0x00, 0x01},
    },
    [1] = {
        .name = "Struct_2",
        .size = 4,
        .value = (uint8_t[]){0x00, 0x01, 0x03, 0x04},
    },
};
```

Comment: @anastaciu Oh, OP said "The following example works well." but it actually won't...

Comment: Yes, recurrent problem :)

Comment: @MikeCAT Code fixed, never heard about compound literals before. Thanks

Comment: @Arkaik, well, only one thing left to do, UV and accept.

Answer (score 0):

`value` is not an array, but a pointer.
You must initialize it by referring to the array that exists elsewhere.

Indeed `name` works differently because the lexical literal syntax for strings `"like this"` create an unnamed array of chars.